# tensorflow converting tensor to python list is too slow

Tags: performance, list, tensorflow, eval, tensor

My goal is feeding tensors to tensorflow algorithm.

I convert tensor object to python list using tensor.eval(), because tensors cannot be fed.

But it takes too long time.

Are there any other methods?

Comment: I would suggest you to post your code you have written so far so people here can help

Comment: The concept of feeding data to placeholders is that your data is not in tensor format and thus you put it in the placeholder... if you already have a tensor containing your data just use that one as input to your network **instead** of the placeholder.